# How to change CSS property with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

This may seem like a simple question, but what I am trying to do is this:

I have a CSS which looks like this:

```
.menu-item:hover ul { height: 50px; }
```

And items like tis:

```
<div class="menu-item">
    <h4><a href="#">About</a></h4>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Biography</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When the h4 item is hovered, I'd like to set that CSS property to some value, let's say 300px. When the mouse leaves, I'd like to reset it back to 50px.

Comment: When the `h4` is hovered you want the `ul` to change height?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use straight CSS:

```
.menu-item h4:hover  { height: 300px; }
.menu-item h4 { height: 50px; }
```

if you want to use jQuery you can do:

```
  $(".menu-item h4").hover(  function(){
   //Mouse Enter
      $(this).css({
        "height": "300px"
      });
   },
   //Mouse Leave
   function(){
      $(this).css({
        "height": "50px"
      });
   } 
}
```

Comment: That would be fine. However, I have multiple divs with the "menu-item" class. And the reason I want to do it with JS is that the height should depend on the number of items...

Comment: If you use the jQuery version then you only target the current h4 that you are hovering on

Answer (score 3):

`h4:hover { height:300px; }`

Pseudo elements in CSS, no Javascript required.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you could just simplfy it and do something like below..

```js
$( "h1" ).hover(function() {
  $( this ).toggleClass( "increase", 1500, "easeOutSine" );
});
```

```css
h1 {
  background-color: green;
  text-align: center;
}
.increase {
  color: red;
  height: 150px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1> change on hover </h1>
```

**Note:**  I added some proprerties just to make the increase in height visible. I also prefer **.ddClass** because **.CSS** adds inline CSS to you document.